# Difference between onView(allOf(withId(R.id.login_card_view), isDisplayed())) and check(matches(isDisplayed()))

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso, hamcrest

What is the difference between

1.`ViewInteraction v = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.login_card_view), isDisplayed()))`

and

2.`v.check(matches(isDisplayed()))`

Whats the use of `isDisplayed()` in 1 if I am doing the same thing in 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isDisplayed` has different semantics in those two contexts.

Imagine that your activity has no views. Look at this unit test **test1**, it will pass successfully, because you're asking espresso to find a view that has a specific text and **is display**. Well espresso didn't find that view, but there is no further checking so there is no exception and unit test function is fine

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    Espresso.onView(Matchers.allOf(ViewMatchers.withText("bla bla lba") ,ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
}
```

But look at the following unit test **test2**, it will fail, because you're telling espresso to find a view that has a specific text then **check if that view is displayed** and that checking didn't pass

```
@Test
public void test2() {
    Espresso.onView(Matchers.allOf(ViewMatchers.withText("bla bla lba"))).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
}
```

I hope it is more clear now

Comment: Must better explanation than on google espresso documentation! Thank you.